# If the same document is ingested at two different times, how to have the same id in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have 50 documents I want to ingest into an index.  So I do this and I have 50 documents I can retrieve if I were to query Elasticsearch.

At a later time, perhaps through an automated process, these same 50 documents end up getting ingested again.  I do a query and I see pairs of documents with everything except for different `_id` value.  Actually the `_id` value which is 20 characters for the pair has characters 0,1 different and characters 16-19 different but characters 2-15 the exact same.  I assume these `_id` are autogenerated, maybe the first 2 characters being some sort of sequence number?

But how would I go about having the document, each time, map to the same `_id`?

I expect each unique document to map to the same `_id` value so that my index is not filled up with the exact same information multiple times.

Comment: you need to provide _id yourself when you post a document, so it does not get auto generated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fingerprint` ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fingerprint-processor.html) to calculate an `_id` field from the fields in your document.

You'll need to decide which fields to use, that is, what makes a document "unique" - is it *all* fields, or are there specific identifier fields you want to use.

Then you define an ingest pipeline such as

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/auto-id
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "fingerprint": {
        "fields": ["field1", "field2", "field3"],
        "target_field": "_id"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When you ingest documents, you specify that you want to use this pipeline

```
POST my-index/_doc?pipeline=id-fingerprint
{
  "field1": "one",
  "field2": "2",
  "field3": 3,
}
```

Comment: Yeah I like that approach.  I will try it out and get back to you.  Honestly it looks like all of the fields are the same from afar in these duplicates.  But not all indices used in ingestion are taking on duplicates.